# Add number to rows based on identical values in selected columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a PostgreSQL database that contains traffic tickets written by a few jurisdictions.

Some jurisdictions don't indicate if multiple tickets are written in one traffic stop. However, that can be inferred by analyzing other fields. Consider this data:

```
ticket_id  timestamp            drivers_license
----------------------------------------------
1          2008-08-07 01:51:00  11111111
2          2008-08-07 01:51:00  11111111
3          2008-08-07 02:02:00  22222222
4          2008-08-07 02:25:00  33333333
5          2008-08-07 04:23:00  44444444
6          2008-08-07 04:23:00  55555555
7          2008-08-07 04:23:00  44444444
```

I can infer that:

- Tickets 1 & 2 were written in a single traffic stop because they share driver's license numbers and timestamps.
- Same for 5 & 7, but notice how ticket 6 is between them. Perhaps another officer was writing a ticket at the same time somewhere else, or data entry operators entered stuff out of order.

I would like to add another column that has a unique ID for each traffic stop. It will not be a primary key for the table because it will have duplicate values. For example:

```
ticket_id  timestamp            drivers_license  stop_id
--------------------------------------------------------
1          2008-08-07 01:51:00  11111111         1
2          2008-08-07 01:51:00  11111111         1
3          2008-08-07 02:02:00  22222222         2
4          2008-08-07 02:25:00  33333333         3
5          2008-08-07 04:23:00  44444444         4
6          2008-08-07 04:23:00  55555555         5
7          2008-08-07 04:23:00  44444444         4
```

I can think of computationally-intensive, greedy algorithm ways of doing this with C#, but is there an efficient SQL query that can work?

Comment: I fail to see how simply adding another column is different from having already a foreign key to driver licenses ...

Comment: It's different because of the timestamp.

Comment: Yup. A single motorist (single DL) could be cited on different occasions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efficient SQL Query FTW!

I'm not at a computer that I can test this on so there is likely some syntax problems; I will fix in the morning, but it is something like this:

```
WITH uniquez as (SELECT timestamp, drivers_license, 
rank() over (ORDER BY timestamp, drivers_license) as counterz 
FROM ticketTable)

UPDATE ticketTable TT
SET stop_id = uniquez.counterz
WHERE uniquez.timestamp = TT.timestamp
AND uniquez.drivers_license = TT.drivers_license
```

Basically, you make a select that groups (partitions) by timestamp and drivers_license and have a row counter that goes with it.  When you do the update, you use this previous select table's row counter as your "stop_id" and updates the columns that match the timestamp and drivers license.

Comment: Whether postgreSQL allows it or not, it's a very bad idea to use ROW_NUMBER() without an ORDER BY clause. In any case, I don't think what you have here works at all. If you partition by timestamp, drivers_license, the row numbering will start at 1 again each time timestamp, drivers_license changes. If you change partition by to ORDER BY, you are closer, but I think you would want DENSE_RANK(), not row_number().

Comment: @SteveKass definitely agree.  Late night programming will have that effect on things.  I will edit.

Comment: -1 You just copied my correct version over your incorrect one without crediting. That's not the recommended way around here - to put it politely.

Comment: I'm getting a strange error with the query I constructed based on this. I opened a separate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643859/postgres-missing-from-clause-entry-error-on-query-with-with-clause.

Comment: Turns out you're missing a FROM clause in the UPDATE statement. After the SET line, you need a **FROM uniquez**.

Answer (score 3):

If you employ the [window function **`rank()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) this becomes amazingly simple:

```
SELECT *
      ,rank() OVER (ORDER BY ts, drivers_license)
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY ticket_id
```

Returns exactly what you asked for.

I renamed your column `timestamp` to `ts`, because `timestamp` is a type name in PostgreSQL and a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in every SQL standard.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet is to create a new table (say, "stops") with DISTINCT timestamps and drivers' license #s, assign row numbers, then update the ticket table from that new table.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ticket_id,timestamp,drivers_license,substr(drivers_license,1,1) as stop_id
FROM traffic_data;
```

Hope this works for u... :)

Comment: It's possible that a person could receive separate tickets in separate stops, so that couldn't work, unfortunately.