# Postgres "missing FROM-clause entry" error on query with WITH clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, with-clause

I am trying to use this query in Postgres 9.1.3:

```
WITH stops AS (
    SELECT citation_id,
           rank() OVER (ORDER BY offense_timestamp,
                     defendant_dl,
                     offense_street_number,
                     offense_street_name) AS stop
    FROM   consistent.master
    WHERE  citing_jurisdiction=1
)

UPDATE consistent.master
SET arrest_id = stops.stop
WHERE citing_jurisdiction=1
  AND stops.citation_id = consistent.master.citation_id;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "stops"
LINE 12: SET arrest_id = stops.stop
                         ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "stops"
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 280
```

I'm really confused. The WITH clause appears correct per Postgres documentation. If I separately run the query in the WITH clause, I get correct results.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks. I was going to say I tried renamed the **stops** table as a diagnostic step, but that's clearly not the issue.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html):

> There are two ways to modify a table using information contained in other tables in the database: using sub-selects, or specifying additional tables in the `FROM` clause.

So you just need a FROM clause:

```
WITH stops AS (
    -- ...
)
UPDATE consistent.master
SET arrest_id = stops.stop
FROM stops -- <----------------------------- You missed this
WHERE citing_jurisdiction=1
  AND stops.citation_id = consistent.master.citation_id;
```

The error message even says as much:

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "stops"

Comment: You're right! They need to give out "bonehead" points here. I think I just earned one.

Comment: @ArenCambre: I think we'd all have an excess of "bonehead" points if there were such a thing :) Some of the hardest problems to see are the ones right in front of your face.

Comment: Very nice answer. Just a small question: it should be FROM stops instead of FROM stop, right?

Comment: @joragupra Yes, it should have been (and now is) `stops`, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This can also happen if you mistype a table name. For example:

```
UPDATE profiles SET name = ( profile.first_name ) WHERE id = 1
```

Instead of `profiles` i incorrectly used `profile` !! This would work:

```
UPDATE profiles SET name = ( profiles.first_name ) WHERE id = 1
```