# Updating 'n' column values of table using dynamic query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I've two tables, **theta** and **convergence_table**, each having same number of columns(7 columns here)
*(w0,w1,...w6; j0,j1,...j6)*. I need to update the 'w' values as *wn=wn-jn*. Here I'm updating the values of theta table with the help of a user-defined datatypes *wt & jt(%rowtype)*.

```
select * into jt from convergence_table;                 
select * into wt from theta

update theta                            
    set w0 =  wt.w0-jt.j0, w1 =  wt.w1-jt.j1, w2 =  wt.w2-jt.j2,    
        w3 =  wt.w3-jt.j3, w4 =  wt.w4-jt.j4, w5 =  wt.w5-jt.j5, 
        w6 =  wt.w6-jt.j6;
```

But, now I've 'n+1' number of columns for both **theta** &  **convergence_table**, so instead of writing the update statement and setting all the values from *w0,w1,w2 .... wn*. Is there a way to write a **dynamic query** to perform the updation for all the column values from *w0* to *wn*.

I'm trying the following the code, but it isn't working ..

```
create or replace function sample(c int)
returns void as $$
declare jt convergence_table%rowtype; wt theta%rowtype;  
    query1 text:=''; query2 text:='';

begin

    select * into jt from convergence_table;                
    select * into wt from theta;

    for i in 0..n 
    loop
        query1 := query1 ||'w'||i||' = '||
        'wt.w'||i||' - jt.j'||i||',';
        end loop;

    query2 := trim(trailing ',' from query1);
    query2 := 'update theta set '||query2||';';
    execute query2;

return;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

This gives me an error ...

> ```
> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "wt"
> LINE 1: update theta set w0 = wt.w0 - jt.j0,w1 = wt.w1 - jt.j1,w2 = ...
>                               ^
> QUERY:  update theta set w0 = wt.w0 - jt.j0,w1 = wt.w1 - jt.j1,w2 = wt.w2 - jt.j2,w3 = wt.w3 - jt.j3,w4 = wt.w4 - jt.j4,w5 = wt.w5 - jt.j5,w6 = wt.w6 - jt.j6;
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function sample(integer) line 20 at EXECUTE statement
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "wt"
> SQL state: 42P01
> Context: PL/pgSQL function sample(integer) line 20 at EXECUTE statement
> ```

Can anyone help out with this?

Comment: Basically, this can be done easily in plpgsql. However, please clarify the task first. You want to *`UPDATE`*, but there is no definition of how to match rows. You make it seem like there is only a single row in each table? In an `UPDATE` there is typically at least one column that isn't changed. If you change all columns, you might as well `DELETE` & `INSERT` - but you still need to define *what* to delete ...

Comment: Yes, theta & covergence table have only single row with 'n' columns. Covergence table gets set of random values in each iteration & thus I've to update theta accordingly
(Wn=W(n-1)-Jn). This is the scenario. 

i.e                     Convergence(J),                theta (W)                      
Initially                     (null),                     (5,4,4,3,3,4,4)             
After 1st iter.     (1,2,3,2,1,4,3)   ->      (4,2,1,1,2,0,1)  
2nd iteration     (2,0,1,2,1,3,2)   ->     (2,2,0,-1,1,-3,-1)

My theta table at the end is (2,2,0,-1,1,-3,-1).
Usually I'll have 1000's of iterations.

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to attach a image, since I'm only a beginner. @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, This is my email ID- mouryathelegend@gmail.com. Please send me your mail Id, So that I can explain you about the problem more precisely.. Thank you

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but I'd rather keep this on-site. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29683602/edit) the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_upd_dyn(_source regclass, _target regclass)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   source_cols text;
   target_cols text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO source_cols
          string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', s.' ORDER BY attname)
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _source
   AND    NOT attisdropped              -- no dropped (dead) columns
   AND    attnum > 0;                   -- no system columns

   SELECT INTO target_cols
          string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', ' ORDER BY attname)
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _target
   AND    NOT attisdropped              -- no dropped (dead) columns
   AND    attnum > 0;                   -- no system columns

   EXECUTE format('UPDATE %s t
                   SET   (%s) = (s.%s)  -- prepend 1st table qual s.
                   FROM  %s s' 
                  -- WHERE t.? = s.?    -- how to join source and target?
                 , _target::text, target_cols
                 , source_cols, _source::text
                 );
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_upd_dyn('convergence_table', 'theta');
```

Generates and executes code like:

```
UPDATE theta t SET (w1, w2, w3) = (s.j1, s.j2, s.j3)
FROM convergence_table s
-- note the missing WHERE condition!
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56aa6/1)

You have been asking a similar question recently:

- [Using dynamic query + user defined datatype in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454240/using-dynamic-query-user-defined-datatype-in-postgres/29505224#29505224)

There are links to more explanation. Like this one:

- [Update multiple columns in a trigger function in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343075/update-multiple-columns-in-a-trigger-function-in-plpgsql/15351196#15351196)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PL/pgsql [EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) command, building your query string from [information_schema.columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/infoschema-columns.html).

Comment: Sorry,I'm new to PostgreSQL and not familiar with that, Is there a way to modify my above code and get the answer ?? @Politank-Z

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643859/postgres-missing-from-clause-entry-error-on-query-with-with-clause

Comment: If I'm not wrong, using the from-clause here won't help, the wt & jt are user-defined types (rowtype). & this indeed would give me another error saying jt & wt doesn't exist. @Politank-Z

Comment: You could use PL/pgsql to compute the results of the subtractions into an array, and use the array to construct your update statement.